# Concat 2 column in one using codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to concatenate the first and the last name as full name in my query.

```
$query = $this->db->select('CONCAT(w.firstName," ",w.lastName) as fullName,w.ID,w.firstName,w.lastName, w.firstname_ar, w.lastname_ar, w.cin , w.tel, w.tel2, w.poste_id, w.gender, w.date_birth, w.address, w.address_ar, w.familySituation, w.socialSecurity, w.typeContract, w.period,w.email,w.status,r.name,w.conge as cng,w.startDateContract, w.pictureProfile, w.endDateContract, w.dateTitulation, w.rib, w.languages, w.passport, w.passport_end_date, w.urgent_phone, w.urgent_phone_name,w.pointage_id as idpointeur, w.shift_start as heure_arr, w.shift_end as heure_dep, w.worker_role as workerRole, r.color as roleColor, r.name as departement, conge_annee, c.name as companyName, c.logo as logoCompany, p.title as poste',FALSE)->from('Workeforce w')->join('Role r', 'r.ID = w.RoleID')->join('Company c', 'c.ID = w.CompanyID')->join('poste p', 'p.id = w.poste_id', 'left')->where('w.worker_role <', 100);
```

And it give me this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT(w.firstName' in 'field list' in
>   /Users/mac/www/application/core/models/workeforce_model.php:100 Stack
>   trace: #0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the quotation marks in your CONCAT.
The fact that your error says that "'CONCAT(w.firstName'" is not a valid column indicates to me that your DB believes the SELECT ends there.

```
CONCAT(w.firstName,\" \",w.lastName) as fullName, ....
```

Adding **\** in front of the quotation mark will escape it.
You can read more on escaping special characters here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html